# Is this bad database design?

Tags: database

I have a table that stores the offered services, another that is child of services and stores the actual services with price, interval(1h , 1m etc).
The problem is that each child service has some caps associated(50~).
So i thought that a service_cap (child_service_id,cap_id,value) would work. The problem is that value might be numeric (0-) or "unlimited" or (available,unavailable,subject to availability).

I think that i can represent with negative values these states otherwise it would be a number...

Some people told me that this is EAV and is bad but i cant think of an alternative..

Answer (score 0):

You can have two columns such as `cap_value` and `cap_type` (pick your own better name) in the `service_cap` table.  The `cap_type` can handle the logic of if the service is available, unavailable, subject, or unlimited.  You can have more status options.  Then you can restrict the `cap_value` to only have a value for certain `interval_types`.

So, unlimited and unavailable should have an empty/null value for `cap_type`.  The other ones can store the needed cap.

Comment: interval is at child_service, it isnt related with the capabilities.. It is like if you buy this package 1h you will have these capabilities..but having the capabilities it isnt true/false.. it can be numeric or unlimited , or subject to availability

Comment: please see my edits above and let me know if that helps, otherwise you might want to clarify some in the original question